# How to configure facets in the MarkLogic App Builder?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I'm using MarkLogic 8 and attempting to build a simple app with app services (http://localhost:8000/appservices). I understand that this feature is deprecated.

I've inserted data in the following XML format:

```
<parent xmlns:wiki = "http://marklogic.com/test">           
        <e1>    string value    </e1>
        <e2>    string value    </e2>
        <e3>    string value    </e3>
        <e4>    string value    </e4>
    </parent>
```

I want each of 'e' nodes to be a facet, where I'm able to click on the range of values and filter the visualization widgets. Neither the facets nor the bars on the bar graphs are displaying, however I can see data in the list view at the bottom and I can effectively search.

I set up element range indexes in the admin console, though the only reason I can think of that it wouldn't work is I didn't specify a correct namespace. **EDIT: Disregard, I'm confident I specificed the namespace correctly.** Any thoughts?

Based on my data, how should I be populating this box?

https://docs.marklogic.com/media/apidoc/9.0/guide/admin/range_index/images/range_add.gif

I just set the type to string and put e1,e2,e3,e4 for the localname and http://marklogic.com/test for the namespace.

Comment: AppServices isn't just deprecated, it's been completely removed from later versions of MarkLogic. The Discovery App - https://github.com/marklogic-community/slush-marklogic-node - is much easier to build, edit and extend. It also has a much nicer UI and many plugins available.

Comment: The link for the discovery app is actually https://github.com/ryanjdew/ml-slush-discovery-app, but the slush generator is definitely a good alternative to app-builder. And even though it is getting a bit dated itself as well, it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Your elements have a namespace declaration for the prefix `wiki`, but none of your elements is actually using that prefix. I think without changing your xml, you'd have to clear the namespace field, since the elements are likely in no-namespace.

I second the comments from Rob though, and highly encourage looking for alternatives. App Builder was deprecated several years ago, and has been completely removed in ML 9. Currently the slush-marklogic-node generator is probably the best front-end alternative, and marklogic-data-hub the best ui for loading and transforming data.

HTH!